# jquery onclick event not working on td

Tags: dom, jquery

I am trying to trigger an event when I click on a `td` with class `toggle`. When I click on a td with class `toggle`, I want to show all the next `tr` with class `hidethis`.

But I cant seem to trigger an event on the `td`. Here's what I have got so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$(' td .toggle ').on('click',function(ev){


$(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr .hidethis').show();


});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>



<table border="1">
<tr >
<td class="toggle">First Toggle</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "hidethis" style="display:none">
<td>Value 1</td>
<td>Value 2 </td>
<td>Value 3</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td class="toggle">Second Toggle</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "hidethis" style="display:none">
<td>Value 4</td>
<td>Value 5 </td>
<td>Value 6</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is  when I click on the `td` with class `toggle` the event is not firing.
Please help me. May be I am not seeing something obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('td.toggle ')` remove the space.

Comment: yes that seemed to solve the problem. thanks. I feel like such an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between the selectors, [it has a specific meaning](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

It should be:

```
$('td.toggle')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between td and toggle

```
$(' td .toggle ').on('click',function(ev){
```

to

```
$('td.toggle').on('click',function(ev){
    ^
```

and also same problem with your below code:-

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr .hidethis').show();
```

to

```
 $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr.hidethis').show();
                                  ^
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M8sQH/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Simply try like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle').on('click',function(ev){
       $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr .hidethis').show();
    });
});
```

Or remove the space between the `td` and its `classname`

```
$('td.toggle').on('click',function(ev){
```